# What is the "dhyan" of laghu shodashi mantra?

Tags: mantras, tantra, sri-vidya

I am looking for dhyan of laghu shodashi mantra which I am not able to find in texts that I have. Please help.

Comment: It is the same as Panchadasi sri matre namaha